# Where does class Eloquent Reside in Laravel 4.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a simple question... 
But google doesn't answer me well this time... 
I want to know where Eloquent class resides in laravel 4.2 which we use to extend the **Model** files
I also searched inside

> vendor/laravel/framework

But couldn't find any class named **Eloquent**
Any Suggestions will be appreciated...

Comment: why don't you just search for it ? "class Eloquent"

Comment: Not found in whole folder :( I have searched before posting question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class is not named `Eloquent`, it's actually named `Model`, but it has an alias created in the `aliases` array from the `app/config/app.php` configuration file, that allows it to be referenced as `Eloquent`:

```
'aliases' => array(
    ...
    'Eloquent' => 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model',
    ...
)
```

The file is located in:

```
vendor/laravel/framework/Illumninate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php
```

Comment: argh...i didn't remember that...+1 for you :)